# What have I done to my /home/user directory?

Tags: files, git

I was planning to initialise a bare git repository in a different location to the `.git` file. Then I somehow deleted my `/home/<user>/` directory, or something. This is what I did:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/

$ mkdir web-test

$ cd ~/
```

I tried to delete a folder in there

```
$ rm foo.git -r
```

(Was putting `-r` after the directory a mistake?)

```
$ git init --separate-git-dir /var/www/html/web-test/ --bare
```

(I realise I forgot to create a folder to put the `.git` file into)

```
$ ls -a
.     .bash_history  .bash_profile  branches  description   HEAD     info
..    .kshrc         refs           .viminfo  .bash_logout  .bashrc  config
.git  hooks          .ipython       objects   .ssh

$ ls ~/ -a
ls: cannot access /home/<user>/: Not a directory

$ echo $PWD
/home/<user>

$ ls /var/www/html/web-test/ -a
.     .bash_history  .bash_profile  branches  description   HEAD     info
..    .kshrc         refs           .viminfo  .bash_logout  .bashrc  config
.git  hooks          .ipython       objects   .ssh

$ file ~
/home/<user>: ASCII text
```

Can someone tell me what I've done?

Comment: I believe you have moved ~ to `/var/www/html/web-test/` and then created the git repository files inside it. You should be able to move it back.

Comment: Yes I see now, the `--separate-git-dir` arg has caused my stuff to be moved there

Answer (score 4):

**Your home directory has been moved to `/var/www/html/web-test/` and you can recover it from there without loss of data.**

---

The current directory (presumably `~`) has been moved to `/var/www/html/web-test/` and a bare git repository created inside it (the "refs" and "objects" directories, among others). A text file has been created in its place that git knows how to follow (like an artificial symlink):

```
gitdir: /var/www/html/web-test/
```

This is the [documented behaviour of `git init --separate-git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt):

> ```
>    --separate-git-dir=<git dir>
>        Instead of initializing the repository as a directory to either
>        $GIT_DIR or ./.git/, create a text file there containing the path
>        to the actual repository. This file acts as filesystem-agnostic Git
>        symbolic link to the repository.
>
>        If this is reinitialization, the repository will be moved to the
>        specified path.
> ```

The last paragraph is the most material one here. The default if you don't specify a path is that the repository you're talking about is in `.`. It would be nice if it offered some hint this would happen before it shot your foot off.

You can delete the text file (`rm ~`) and move the directory back (`mv /var/www/html/web-test ~`) and everything should be fine.

You might want to delete the git files afterwards - at the moment you have two git repositories based in that directory, which git probably isn't going to like even if that was what you wanted.